# Searching Through a Database

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a database table with 2 columns, one of them stores the `PlainText` and the other stores the `Md5Hash` of the `PlainText`.

I am trying to search through my database from C# for a required `PlainText` when given the `MDF5Hash`.

I have tried:

```
com.CommandText = "Select PlainText from dbo.CryptTable where Md5Hash='" + textBox1.Text + "'";

try
{
    com.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    MessageBox.Show(com.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

given the correct `MdFHash` I am receiving `-1` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`. It will return first cell from first row of results, which is exactly what you need.

> [**`ExecuteScalar()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

> [**`ExecuteNonQuery()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: @Parisa You're welcome! You should also know that your current code is  vulnerable. You should read about SQL Injection and try making it more safe.